# Splittings files in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file-io

I have a method in my application that splits a file into many smaller files.

The method opens a tabular delimited file and for each line in the file it adds a the first value in the line to a file that it creates, which is named off of values in that line. For instance, in a row with the following values:

Atlanta     Boston      354      Goalie

It would add the value 'Atlanta' to a file called 'Boston.csv'.

```
def split_file(file)    
   File.open(file.decompressed_file_path, 'rb').each { |line|
     row_values = line.split("\t")

     file_name = build_file_name(file,row_values)
     file_path = build_file_path(file_name)

     open(file_path, "a+") { |f| f << row_values[0] + "\n" }
   }
end



def build_file_path(name)
  File.join(file.directory,name)
end


def build_file_name(file,row_values)
  "#{row_values[file.hometown_index]}.csv"
end
```

My question is, is there a more efficient way of accomplishing this? A quicker way to be more specific or is this just a tedious task.

Comment: More efficient in what way? Your solution seems to be about as minimal as possible considering your requirements. The only "costly" operation in there is reading every line of the file, but you cannot optimize that one away :-) Aside from that, optimizing working code is generally not on-topic for this site. Instead, try [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The CSV module *might* be faster, but you'd need to test and see.  Fortunately your program is small enough that a conversion isn't hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question wheter there is more efficient way of accomplishing your task depends on what do you mean by "efficient" and in what way do you reuse your code. Obviously, computational complexity is not a question here, so you must be asking about ergonomical efficiency. The code you wrote is good enough.

But if you want to refactor it from good to great, you would be invited to make more thorough use of object-oriented techniques. For example, you would write an object `RowValues`:

```
class RowValues < Array
  def self.of line
    new line.split "\t"
  end

  def build_file_name file
    "#{self[file.hometown_index]}.csv"
  end

  def write file_path
    open( file_path, "a+" ) { |f| f << self[0] + "\n" }
  end
end

def split_file file
  File.open(file.decompressed_file_path, 'rb').each { |line|
    row_values = RowValues.of line
    file_name = row_values.build_file_name file
    file_path = build_file_path file_name
    row_values.write file_path
  }
end
```

You could continue refactoringg along these lines, for example making `#split_file` an instance method of your file object, so instead of `split_file( file )` you would call `file.split`. I do not fully understand your code, for example, in your `#build_file_path` method you use `file` variable (or method) which is not declared in your code. In any case, I recommend you watching the lecture by Ben Orenstein, [Refactoring from good to great](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DC-pQPq0acs).

Comment: Eh, you call `build_file_name` on the `row_values` variable, but that is an `Array` (the result of `line.split "\t"`).

Comment: A subclass of `Array`, on which I have defined a `#build_file_name` method, just like in the OP.

Comment: No, you return an instance of `Array`, not of `RowValues`. `String#split` does not magically return a `RowValues`? `(RowValues.of "hi").class => Array`.

Comment: I remedied that. I forgot to call `#new` in my `#of` class method.